# Why are x_train & y_train different shapes while their values are assigned by one dataset?

Tags: python

When splitting the MNIST dataset into `x_train` and `y_train`, why are the two resulting arrays different shapes?

```
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

print(x_train.shape) >>> (60000, 28, 28)
print(y_train.shape) >>> (60000,)
```

Comment: No one will be able to help you with your question as written, please review [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: There's enough information to answer the question

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using the MNIST dataset based on the dimensions, the reason why the shapes of `x_train` and `y_train` are different is because they contain different information. `x_train` contains the 28x28 pixel handwritten drawing, which is why you see the `28, 28` in `x_train.shape`, while `y_train` contains the number the handwritten digit corresponds to

Comment: @AyeshaMustafa Please consider accepting the answer if it solved your problem.